# How can async / await be used with forEach?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

How can `async` / `await` be used to achieve the following?

```
self.onmessage = event => {

  // async stuff in forEach needs to finish
  event.data.search.split(',').forEach((s, i) => {
    db.get('customers').then(doc => {
      ...
    })
  })

  // before getting here
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the [documentation on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/925/async-functions-async-await/7746/looping-with-async-await#t=201703052353271956842) would help...

Comment: async/await will make this code unnecessarily complicated - always use the best tools for the job, not necessarily the newest shiny gadgets :p

Comment: in fact, `await/async` wont help at all

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thanks.  That's good to know.  Do you have any resources showing which situations are better for async / await and which are better for promises?

Comment: async/await are built on Promises; you should be using them together. It's not like they are mutually exclusive...

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah - to be honest, I've never found a use for async/await - I don't like backwards step in programming style it requires :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` and replace your call to `Array#forEach` with `Array#map`:

```
self.onmessage = async (event) => {

  // async stuff in forEach needs to finish
  await Promise.all(event.data.search.split(',').map((s, i) => {
    return db.get('customers').then(doc => {
      ...
    })
  }))

  console.log('All finished!')

}
```

Comment: If `Promise.all` does the job on it's own, the previous version of the answer is preferable to me.

Comment: Do you intend to return a result from the `then` after each database call? If not, you can remove the `result` variable and just know that everything is finished by the time that `console.log` line is reached.

Comment: Without async/await, you would need to use an extra `.then` to know when your loop has finished. I think this third revision is the best of both worlds